# Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s) on non primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

**Problem**: I'd like to do is update a row(entity) without fetching first.
I know this has been posted many times but I can't seem to find any answer related to my scenario.
I'm trying to update a row using a value that is not the primary key (ServiceBusSequenceNumber).

**Attempt 1**

**Error**:

> Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s)

**Code**:

```
var ybEvent = new YogabandEvent() { ServiceBusSequenceNumber = 4 };
using (var dbContext = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
{
    ybEvent.Status = EventStatus.Completed;
    dbContext.Entry<YogabandEvent>(ybEvent).State = EntityState.Modified;
    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

**Attempt 2**

**Error**:

> "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_YogabandEvents_Yogabands_YogabandId". The conflict occurred in database "yogabandy2020-dev", table "dbo.Yogabands", column 'Id'.\nThe statement has been terminated."

**Code**:

```
var ybEvent = new YogabandEvent() { ServiceBusSequenceNumber = 4 };
using var dbContext = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
dbContext.YogabandEvents.Attach(ybEvent);
ybEvent.Status = EventStatus.Completed;
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

**FYI**: I can do an update with a fetch first, like this below, but I'd like to update the row without fetching first:

```
using var dbContext = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
var ybEvent = await dbContext.YogabandEvents.Where(p => p.ServiceBusSequenceNumber == 4).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
ybEvent.Status = EventStatus.Completed;
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: You cannot insert a key that is already in the table.  You must use Update.

Comment: Can you provide a short example?

Comment: @jdweng yes, but that error is "you cannot insert a child row that doesn't reference a parent row"

Comment: If you are updating a record but not fetching it first, you MUST provide the primary key so EF knows what record is being updated.  Also, you should be aware that properties that are NULL in your c# will get updated to NULL in the database.  EF doesn't track property modifications.  It tracks object modifications. and it updates ALL of the properties and so if you don't provide the values, they will get updated to NULL.

Comment: The error says : "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint"

Comment: Just download the row first, it'll save a world of pain, or issue an SQL raw for UPDATE yogabands SET eventstus='completed' WHERE servicebusnumber = 4?

Comment: @jdweng indeed, which is why I made the comment that I did. Had the error said "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint" I'd have agreed with your "You cannot insert a key that is already in the table"

Comment: I know I can fetch/download the first row, then update, but my question is around whether or not I can update the row without fetching first and not having the primary key to do it.

Comment: @user1186050 *issue an SQL raw for `UPDATE yogabandevents SET eventstatus='completed' WHERE servicebussequencenumber = 4`?*

Comment: @user1186050 : not using EF.  you must use raw TSQL in your c# code in order to do that

Comment: so EF can't do it?

Comment: EF can do it, but it's a world of pain discovering all the necessary data not to wreck the row. Just download the row (or use a rawsql via EF, which is still "ef doing it" right?). EF's geared towards having certain entities C# side map to certain rows db side. If multiple rows have ServiceBusSequenceNumber = 4 then it blows away that 1:1 mapping

Comment: @user1186050 : EF can not update just one property like how you're attempting to do it.  Use a SQL update statement if you want to do it that way.

Comment: ok, I understand now. Thanks for the help in understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is essentially because of how change tracking works. When you do `new YogabandEvent` and don't specify the Primary key value, it's seen as a new entity, so it tries to insert that new entity.

Comment: ok, understood. But is there a way to update/edit an entity without fetching the row first and not having the primary key. I only have another column value that is indexed.

Comment: perhaps also clarify what will happen to all of the other properties that aren't given values to the new entity created in c#?  EF doesn't just update the one property...

Comment: All the other properties should be left alone and not changed

Comment: @user1186050 : then you need to provide values to those properties if you're using EF to do the update, or, skip EF and use TSQL in your c# to specify the one property that should get updated.

Comment: ok, so basically EF cannot do it unless I provide all other values?

Comment: @user1186050 : correct.  EF updates ALL properties to the values in your c# entity and if those properties are NULL in your c# entity, they will get updated to NULL in your database

Comment: Right. The fact that all other properties have their default values (because you didn't set them on the `new` object) it's trying to insert a new entity with all default (e.g. null) values except the `ServiceBusSequenceNumber` and `Status` that you set.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to fetch the entity to update it?